# OpenThread: NRFX_LOG_INFO() / NRF_LOG_INFO() - How to enable them?

Tags: nrf52, openthread

I have a some question. I would like to use one of the USB log macros like `NRFX_LOG_INFO()` and `NRF_LOG_INFO()`. But when I set `NRF_LOG_ENABLED 1` in `sdk_config.h` and include `nrf_log.h` into my file in openthread/examples/platforms/nrf528xx/src/` I get the following error:

```
rf_log.h:55:10: fatal error: nrf_strerror.h: No such file or directory
 #include "nrf_strerror.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What should I do to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in Github issue: https://github.com/openthread/openthread/issues/5285

`In OpenThread repository the NRF_LOG module is not usable (only stubbed). For logging purpose, you can use either OpenThread's otPlatLog functionality in vanilla OpenThread, or download the nRF5 SDK for Thread and Zigbee which gives you full functionality of NRF Logger.`